# Definitions of maximal/minimal/least and smallest elements for strict partial orders

Tags: order-theory

Since strict partial orders are irreflexive, antisymmetric and transitive, I am confused as to how they can have minimal/maximal elements as surely these would be undefined due to them not being able to have terms that are the same?

Can we actually define minimal/maximal definitions for strict partial orders?

Additionally, is the definition for least/greatest for a strict partial order as follows:

a is least is defined as for all b in a, a < b
a is greatest is defined as for all b in a, b < a
Does this need any other conditions?

Thank you!

Comment: Not all partial orders have a minimum or a maximum (even on a finite set).  But some do, even if they are not total orders.  Take for example the first picture in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is the maximum (greatest element) of a set $A$ if $a \in A$ and for all $b \in A$ we have $b=a$ or $a < b$.

The minimum (least element of $A$) is defined analogously.  These need not exist.

$a \in A$ is a *maximal element* of $A$  iff no $b \in A$ exists such that $a < b$.

A minimal element is again defined analogously. A maximum is maximal, but the reverse need not hold etc.